# Rails::Engine routes not being loaded in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, mount, rails-engines

I'm having a really strange problem whereby my routes are working fine in development mode but not in production.

The majority of my app is contained within an engine, which is loaded into the main application, and the routes file the main app starts like this...

```
SandersteadParish::Application.routes.draw do
  mount Cms::Engine => "/cms"
```

The first few line of my routes file in the engine look like this...

```
Cms::Engine.routes.draw do
  scope '(groups/:group_id)' do
  resources :pages do
    resources :widgets
      collection do
      post :layout, :add_panel, :split_panel
    end
  end
```

If I run RAILS_ENV=development rails server, the routes work fine, but if I run RAILS_ENV=production, they don't get loaded.

Comment: Have you included that gem in your Gemfile? 
Like this for example: `gem 'cms', path: 'engines/cms'`

Answer (score 0):

when you add add engine is "isolated" by default this means all it routes needs to be accessed with the engine scope for example `Cms.pages_path` you can find more info here http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#routes